# How to create array of object in javascript explicitly

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, path

I receive a file path string like so:

```
let sampletext="Home/Student/Hello.txt";
```

And I want to convert this into the following structure dynamically. How should I best go about this?

```
let idarray=[
    {
        'id':'Home',
        'parent': '',
    },
    {
        'id':'Student',
        'parent': 'Home',
    },
    {
        'id':'Hello.txt',
        'parent': 'Student',
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```js
let sampletext="Home/Student/Hello.txt"

let textarr = sampletext.split('/');
let idarray = textarr.map((x, i) => {
  if(i === 0)
    return { id: x, parent: '' };
  
  return { id: x, parent: textarr[i - 1] };
});

console.log(idarray);
```

Answer (score 1):

`split` on `/` and then build it from there - you can do this concisely with `map`:

```js
let sampletext="Home/Student/Hello.txt";

let componentsArr = sampletext.split("/");
let idarray = componentsArr.map(( id, i ) => ({
    id,
    parent: componentsArr[i - 1] || ""
}));

console.log(idarray);
```

This is very simple - just set the `id` property to be whatever value you're currently iterating over, and then if there exists a value before it (i.e. if this is not the first/root item) then set its `parent` value to the previous value; otherwise, it's an empty string. You could remove `componentsArr` and refer to the splitting `n` times but that's mildly inefficient in my opinion.

Comment: Great minds think alike it seems!

Comment: @Swiffy yes they do indeed :)

Comment: Too bad it's not possible to chain the `.map` to the `.split` because you don't have the array reference there.

Comment: I mean you could - just replace `componentsArr` with another `split` inside the `map` (as I detailed later in my answer, though, this causes efficiency concerns but is indeed much more concise)